# Object detection using tensorflow pretrained faster_rcnn

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use a tensorflow's pretrained model to do some object classification.

I downloaded `faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_lowproposals_oid_2018_01_28` from tensorflow, but I have some trouble to make predictions. Here is the code I run.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2

model_folder = "faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_lowproposals_oid_2018_01_28"

model_graph_file = model_folder+"/frozen_inference_graph.pb"
model_weights_file = model_folder+"/model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001"

graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
graph_def.ParseFromString(tf.gfile.Open(model_graph_file,'rb').read())

with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def=graph_def, name="")

#for op in graph.get_operations():
#    print(op.name)

print([n.name + '=>' +  n.op for n in graph_def.node if n.op in ('Placeholder')])

input = graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
classes = graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
scores = graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
boxes = graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')

pandas_image = cv2.imread('resources/some_image.jpg')
print(pandas_image.shape)

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    classes_out,scores_out,boxes_out  = sess.run([classes,scores,boxes],feed_dict={input:pandas_image})
    print(classes_out)
    print(scores_out)
    print(boxes_out)
```

But I get the following error on `sess.run()` :

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (980, 1680, 3) for Tensor 'image_tensor:0', which has shape '(?, ?, ?, 3)'
```

I guess I must resize my input image to match the size of my input layer. What is the correct way to do this ? How can I know the size of the input layer ?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

As the error says the shape of the tensor you are passing to the model is wrong.
Usually the model expects the images to be of shape (batch_size,224,244,3) but this 224 might vary depending on the model and I recommend you consult the documentation/example code to decide this size.

Comment: Actually the model include an `image_resizer`, so the dimension of the input image is not a problem. It was actually that I can't just pass my image directly as input. I must put it in an array (batch_size = 1) : `feed_dict={input:[pandas_image]}`